# Hapi-HL7-Terser, segments order when creating a message using terser

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

I am trying to create an HL7 message using code similar to the following:

```
Message message = new DefaultModelClassFactory().getMessageClass("ADT_A01", "2.3", false).newInstance();
Terser terser = new Terser(message);
terser.set("FHS-1-1","|");
... similar terser.set calls for other FHS fields
terser.set("BHS-1-1","|");
... similar terser.set calls for other BHS fields
terser.set("MSH-1-1","|");
... similar terser.set calls for other MSH fields
```

and what I need is that the generated message would have the segments in the order:
FHS
BHS
MSH

while the actual result is:
FHS
MSH
BHS

so my question is, is there a way to control the order of the generated segments when using HAPI terser? or is there a way to force the terser to generate the segments in the same order as they are created using the set method?

Answer (score 1):

According the defintion `.getMessageClass(String theName, String theVersion, boolean isExplicit)` your usage of `.getMessageClass` 
seems to be wrong.

Try something like that

```
DefaultModelClassFactory().getMessageClass("ADT_A01", "2.5",false).newInstance();
```

Comment: well you are right about that, but it is not the problem, it was a typo when I wrote the code here, but in my code I am setting the version and message type correctly...sorry about that
I am just wondering if there is a way to control the order in which the segments get generated, it seems random to me, I am sure there is some logic behind it, but I just couldn't find anything regarding that in the documentations.

Comment: Did you check your template for ADT^A01? I guess you could create a new template or modify an already existing one according your needs.

Comment: good point, but I actually got the same result with all templates that I tried.

Comment: I tried using a generic message, like this
message = new GenericMessage.UnknownVersion(new DefaultModelClassFactory());
and also got the same result...

Comment: Maybe hapi does not support batch file processing.

Comment: yeah I think it doesn't... I wrote my own code that manipulates the message to fit my requirement... thank you very much for your help :)